# Open XML SDK when creating a document, the current html page is constantly returned

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a word document with my own text inside using the Open XML SDK, but whatever I enter there, I always get a document in which my copied html page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybR0H.png)

Here is the method I use:

```
 public IActionResult GenerateDocxBrowser()
        {

            using (MemoryStream mem  = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument =
                    WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
                {
                    // Add a main document part. 
                    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();

                    // Create the document structure and add some text.
                    mainPart.Document = new Document();
                    Body docBody = new Body();

                    // Add your docx content here
                    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
                    Run r = new Run();
                    Text t = new Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent quam augue, tempus id metus in, laoreet viverra quam. Sed vulputate risus lacus, et dapibus orci porttitor non.");
                    r.Append(t);
                    p.Append(r);
                    docBody.Append(p);

                }


                var cd = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileNameStar = "ABC.docx"
                };

                Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());
                return File(mem.ToArray(),"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `docBody` be appended to the `mainPart.Document`? By the looks of it whatever is created in docBody is lost.

Comment: I added mainPart.Document.AppendChild(docBody); but it didn't help. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-word-processing-document-by-providing-a-file-name#sample-code . Also add `wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();` to save the document.

Comment: content using (WordprocessingDocument I changed it many times, even left it empty, it doesn't change the result 
it seems to me that the reason is here, but without this, when there is no saving
var cd = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileNameStar = "ABC.docx"
                };
                
                Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());